# Extra null when a struct is printed with writeln

Tags: d

In the code below what is that extra `null` in the output when an instance of `S2` is printed with `writeln` ?

```
$ dmd -de -w so_004.d && ./so_004
S1("A", 1)
S2("A", 1, null)
```

If I define `S2` in a package scope (i.e. outside `main` function) the `null` disappears.

Compiled with a reasonable recent DMD:

```
$ dmd --version
DMD64 D Compiler v2.083.0
Copyright (C) 1999-2018 by The D Language Foundation, All Rights Reserved written by Walter Bright
```

I noticed the issue when I was learning `opEquals` and I'm not planning to define types in sub-scopes in "real" code.

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
  {
    struct S1 { string id; ushort x; }
    auto a = S1("A", 1);
    assert(a == a);
    writeln(a);
  }

  {
    struct S2 {
      string id; ushort x;
      bool opEquals()(auto ref const string rhs) const {
        return id == rhs;
      }
    }

    auto a = S2("A", 1);
    assert(a == "A");
    writeln(a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the context pointer (called `this` in `S2.tupleof`), referring to the stack frame on which the `S2` instance is created. This would generally be used in code like this:

```
auto fun(int n) {
    struct S {
        int get() { return n; }
    }
    return S();
}
```

The above code would allocate `n` on the heap, and place a pointer to it in `S`'s `this` member.

Now, as for why it's in your code - [that's a bug](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10276). There's no need for the context pointer, as the struct is not using any variables from its scope. To remove it, simply mark `S2` as `static`:

```
static struct S2 {
    string id; ushort x;
    bool opEquals()(auto ref const string rhs) const {
        return id == rhs;
    }
}

auto a = S2("A", 1);
writeln(a); // S2("A", 1)
```